# CSS menu list items need to show inside div container

Tags: jquery, css, html, menu, overflow

I'm using this drop down menu: [css-tricks simple jquery drop down](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SimplejQueryDropdowns/), and I need it to show up fully within another div.

My div is a draggable `$('#textbox')`. You can see it in the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/asaakius/5nGYS/13/. I've put the relevant CSS within this jsfiddle.

You'll see there's a draggable box with an `x`, this the the menu that can be rolled over. The problem is that the menu should show up **inside** the textbox, but it doesn't. I think it's because it overflows out of `$('#textbox')` on the right. Is there a way this menu can be oriented to show up on the left?

I've also put a flat x on the side of the page, not part of any container, so you know how the menu looks when it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5nGYS/15/).
Here's what I did:
First, the drop-down menu inside the draggable wasn't showing up at all. I put the dropdown menu `ul` inside the `li` that has the "x" button. Then, in the CSS rule for `ul.dropdown ul` (right after `/* LEVEL TWO */`), I changed `left: 0;` to `right: 0;` and changed the width to make it fit inside the draggable.
Hope this helps!
Note: if you want the dropdown text to be aligned right, add `text-align: right;` to the `ul.dropdown ul` rule.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/5nGYS/17/

Comment: With your fiddle, the menu comes out, whereas with mine and Abraham's, they are inside the textbox so that when it is resized and made smaller, part of the menu gets hidden, which I don't want. Which part of the CSS did you use to let your menu stay on top of the textbox?

Comment: It's all about position relative and absolute combined with left, top and right. That is for positioning. The menu stays on top of the textbox because it has a higher z-index